# How to Display Dress/Cloth for Microsoft kinect skeletons

Tags: virtual, kinect

I am trying to develop a virtual fit room app in Microsoft kinectSDK. I want to show the dress on the skeletons.
Can anyone tell me which of the following item is better one.

1)Draw the whole  Dress on user skeleton
2)Draw the texture on the each and every joints of the skeletons

I try to do with the 1st option  but I want show the dress or alter the dress if the user turns right or left side.
Can anyone help in displaying the cloth on user skeleton when he turns too. So if the user turns right or left the cloth should get  aligned. Is this possible to do by normal jpeg image? Or have to create any other special type of images(not sure anykind of 3D images).

Regards,
Jayakumar Natarajan

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, you need to render a [skinned](http://home.metrocast.net/~chipartist/SkinTute/), [skeletally animated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation) 3D model that can attach different parts corresponding to clothing items, similar to what the XBox Live avatar does.

For flexible clothing that needs to billow/react to movement, you will have to use some sort of [cloth physics](http://cg.skeelogy.com/introduction-to-soft-body-physics-in-xna/) to move that little bit around properly.

It is impossible to explain all the necessary concepts here. You will probably have to work your way through displaying a skinned model and animating based on the Kinect skeleton - to attaching different meshes based on the clothing outline (and possibly changing the material to enable color/material variations) - to adding elements that can flex/behave realistically.

Answer (score 1):

Using XNA is definitely the best answer. There's a very good example given in Microsoft Kinect Developer Toolkit named "Aveteering XNA". Have a look at it.
Also, if you need a skeleton to skin 3d modeled clothes, you can try the skeleton which comes with the model (dude.FBX) in that Sample application. You can download the Kinect Toolkit here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx